# Outdoor spigot broken pipe on my backyard. Can I just add a cap on the broken pipe?

Tags: pipe, outdoor, leaking, spigot

I have a broken pipe on my backyard. It connects to spigot.
Just recently bought a house, and the house is old; it was built around 1970s. The outdoor spigot always dripped water even when it was fully turned on and off. The pipe is now broken, and I do not need a spigot outdoor.

Below is the image of the broken pipe. It has a thread on the top and also on the bottom of the hex fitting. Can I use a cap on the broken pipe? How can I make sure that the water doesn't leak from the cap, and what else do I need to worry about.

I added a foam on the outside of the pipe as it was snowing. I removed the coating on the pipe, and the magnet was finally sticking to the pipe.

Update: I removed the hex fitting on the pipe, and used a hose cap; no more leaking. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can put a cap on any pipe.   If threaded then tefon pipe tape or paste should prevent leaking.  Is there a shut off valve inside for that pipe?  Would make life easy.

Comment: what is it made off, it is not steal, pVC or copper

Comment: @crip659 i don't see any valve,; it is likely in the crawl space.

Comment: @Ruskes it is metal for sure, it is getting rusty, and the water has a reddish color to it when I turned it on initially.

Comment: It would be important to know the material since fixing it will depend on it. I do not think it is metal, despite the color of water coming out. Use kitchen magnet and check if it is steal, if it sticks it is, if not it could be copper or pvc

Comment: @Ruskes i had to remove the coating, and the magnet stick to the pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are not saying, it is a part of a fountain.

That is a decorative fountain pipe, with metal inside and stone (or just foam) on outside.

The stone has cracked, but the leak comes from the metal screw in, if it is foam, it can be glued together.

Remove (unscrew it) and apply teflon tape then screw back in and the leaking shall stop.

If you do not want to use it anymore, unscrew it go to hardware store and find the right screw in plug.

Comment: I'm not sure that is decorative stone. It may be, but looks like foam pipe insulation to me.

Comment: @RMDman or that

Comment: I added a foam on the outside after the pipe broke, and it was snowing. The pipe is connected to a spigot, which is used to water the backyard.

Answer (score 1):

The hardware store should have rubber plugs with a metal washer on each side, a bolt connecting those, and a thmbscrew. Get the appropriate size, stopper the pipe, and crank down the screw to squeeze the washers tight against the rubber and the rubber tight against the pipe. This is only a temporary fix, but it works no matter what the pipe is made of, and can be installed despite the flowing water if you shove hard.

By the way, the insulation may not help much here. Insulation will slow loss of heat, but without fresh water flowing through it will still be at risk of freezing and bursting the pipe (or ejecting the plug). You might actually want to consider allowing a trickle of water to escape to protect against that.